# Getting error error date/time field value out of range perhaps you need a different datestyle setting on tomcat startup.bat

Tags: angular, postgresql, tomcat

Whenever I am starting my web application my api's are failing and I am getting the error "error date/time field value out of range perhaps you need a different datestyle setting"
on my webapp and on tomcat startup.bat also.

[image: screen shot with the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are running sends a query that relies on a certain setting of the parameter `DateStyle`, which is bad practice and fragile coding (I would file a bug report):

```
... WHERE to_date(...) = '11/31/2021'
```

You should set

```
datestyle = 'US, DMY'
```

in `postgresql.conf` (and reload) to make PostgreSQL accept such strings as valid `date` literals.